# Android set image right after text in button

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How do I set an image right after the text (right side of text) in Xamarin.Android.

I have tried the following code:

```
Control.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, drawable , null);
```

This sets the image at the extreme right of the button and not right after the text

Answer (score 0):

SetCompoundDrawable always sets the image to the Drawables' intrinsic bounds. Thus it will appear at the left, top, right and bottom of the view.

Thus if you need it to appear next to a text, then you have to create your own view which looks like a button.

Ex :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="5dip" >


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout
```